# If using an anagram solver is possible/permitted in Scrabble, what additional strategies should you use?

Tags: scrabble

Often on online multiplayer apps of Scrabble and Words With Friends, you have unlimited time to make your move. As a result, most people use anagram solvers to "cheat". However, because this "cheating" is so common, it's been the norm and possibly may need to use it to be competitive in the app.

What additional strategies should you use given that you have an anagram solver tool? I would think aiming to get "Bingo" more often, playing 7 letters to get 50 bonus points.

Comment: I think I once read that some high-level players *avoid* making bingo plays because, while it does give you a lot of points on that one turn, it can reduce your points for the next few turns since your whole set of tiles will be totally random after a bingo, so there's no way to plan ahead and no guarantee that you can do anything good at all on the next turn. I can't find the reference though, so take this with appropriate skepticism :)

Answer (score 1):

### Take advantage of the board

If both players play the same number of tiles, then they will on average play the same number of points.  By playing your tiles on the multipliers of the board, you can increase the number of points you get to greater heights than your opponent, while denying your opponent the ability to use those same multipliers

### Prevent your opponent from taking advantage of the board.

It is only possible to play on squares that are accessible to the existing tiles on the board.  Your opponent will play immediately after you - they have an opportunity to use any multipliers that you've uncovered before you get a chance.  Deny them this opportunity whenever possible!

### Use as many tiles as possible

The number of tiles you draw each round is dependent on the number of tiles you play.  So if you play exclusively 6 tile words while your opponent plays only 3 tile words, then you will end up drawing twice as many tiles than your opponent, which means you will have access to twice as many points.  This is in addition to the massive point bonus achieved for using all 7 tiles, which should be taken advantage of whenever possible.

### Maximize the use of your high value tiles

A multiplier space is only as good as the tile you place on it.  A 3x letter multiplier is only worth 2 extra points if you play an 'S' on it.  But if you play a 'Z' on it, it's worth 20 extra points.

### Maximize the use of the existing tiles on the board.

The points you get are more than just the tiles in your hand - it's also the tiles already on the board that are part of your word.  That means you should look for ways to use the high value letters already on the board in order to add their points to your own, and to prevent your opponent from using them.

---

Very frequently, these strategies will be in conflict with each other.  It is up to you to weigh them and figure out which one is to your maximum benefit at any given point in the game.